# Where exactly is the Ink Container?

Tags: fallout-3

In Fallout 3 you need an Ink Container for a side quest. I know it's somewhere in the

> Arlington Library.

I'm afraid I may have already picked it up and sold it without noticing (hey, I do a little scaving). Can anyone tell me where it would be if I haven't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ink container is a quest item so it cannot be sold or dropped.  According to http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ink_container there is a bug on the Xbox 360 version that causes it to disappear, but it will reappear when you go to turn in the quest.  If you are on the PC and the item is somehow lost, you could always use the console to hack it into your inventory.